# (NSNotificationCenter) How to add observers in different classes?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

Can someone explain how to use notification center if I want to add observers in different classes? For example: post a notification in classA. Then, add two observers, one in classB and another one in classC, both waiting for the same notification.

I understand that I can use NSNotificationCenter to send and receive notifications like this. What do I need to add to each class in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Apple can explain this very well: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is exactly what notificationCenter is for: It is essentially a bulletin board where classes can post stuff other classes might be interested in, without having to know them (or care if anyone is actually interested).

So a class that has something interesting to tell (Class A from your question) just posts a Notification to the central bulletin board:

```
//Construct the Notification
NSNotification *myNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"SomethingInterestingDidHappenNotification"
                                                               object:self //object is usually the object posting the notification
                                                             userInfo:nil]; //userInfo is an optional dictionary

//Post it to the default notification center
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:myNotification];
```

In each class that's interested in getting notified (classes B and C in your question), you just add yourself as an observer to the default notification center:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@SEL(methodYouWantToInvoke:) //note the ":" - should take an NSNotification as parameter
                                             name:@"SomethingInterestingDidHappenNotification" 
                                           object:objectOfNotification]; //if you specify nil for object, you get all the notifications with the matching name, regardless of who sent them
```

You also implement the method specified in the `@SEL()` part above in your classes B and C. A simple example would look like this:

```
//The method that gets called when a SomethingInterestingDidHappenNotification has been posted by an object you observe for
- (void)methodYouWantToInvoke:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Reacting to notification %@ from object %@ with userInfo %@", notification, notification.object, notification.userInfo);
    //Implement your own logic here
}
```

Comment: so, at class interface I don't have to code nothing? sorry Im new in this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. You do not have to declare any new methods (exceot the one that reacts to the incoming notification in your classes B and C).

Comment: Thansk! I fixed it last Friday.

Answer (score 2):

To send a notification, you want to call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NotificationName" object:nil];
```

To receive a notification, you'll need to call

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(methodNameToCallWhenNotified)
                                                 name:@"NotificationName"
                                               object:nil];
```

and then, to remove that class as an observer, you can use

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Also, see [Apple's NSNotificationCenter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

So what's the problem? You just add them all. That's the cool thing about notifications. When the notification is posted each observer will perform its own selector. That's it

Comment: Hi Andrey, the problem is the next:
I have 3 classes, at classA is where I post the notification; in classB I'm adding an observer (this observer works ok); in classC I[m adding a new one in the same way as classB (both responds to the same notification string) but at log file I saw that only ClassB observer was triggered.